# xcode15 will freze for 3mins when hit a breakpoint

Tags: ios, xcode15

When I launch launch the app happens when hit a new breakpoint, and the xcode will freeze for 3mins, then it will be crash. anysolution? its wasting my time.

the xcode continue print the log below: (arm64)

/Users/sanjiusijiushijingshan/szplusnews/SZPlusNews/SZPlusNews/ThirdParty/TXLoginoauthSDK/TXLoginoauthSDK.framework/TXLoginoauthSDK(TXLoginUIModel.o) 0x00002133: unable to locate module needed for external types: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/DR87TTK87G07/CoreGraphics-1TH4RJJRQVFOC.pcm error: '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/DR87TTK87G07/CoreGraphics-1TH4RJJRQVFOC.pcm' does not exist Debugging will be degraded due to missing types. Rebuilding the project will regenerate the needed module files.

launch app and freeze

Comment: Finally I found the aws, Add -Wl,-ld_classic to / Build Settings / Other Linker Flags. And I don't know why~